# Is there a way to populate a list of complex objects from a stored procedure in C# in blazor server using .net 8?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm currently working with a Blazor server project, using Sql Server stored procedures, C# and .net 8.   Basically the goal is to display log files from the stored procedure - it will be pretty minimal read only data.  My current code looks like

Object

```cs
[Keyless]
public class LogItem
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
    
  public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

DB Context

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
namespace MyAdmin.Data
{
  public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
  {
    public virtual DbSet<ModernQuoteRequest> ModernQuoteRequests { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Calling Code

```cs
using var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    
var LogItems = await context.Set<LogItems>().FromSqlRaw("exec dbo.GetLogItems").ToListAsync();
```

I get a variety of errors using all of the usual combinations of configurations.

Has anyone ever gotten anything like this work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to override `OnModelCreating` and add mapping for `LogItem`
like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<LogItem>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
}
```

Then your calling code you are using LogItem**s** instead of **LogItem**
so your calling code should be updated like this

```
var logItems = await context.Set<LogItem>().FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.GetLogItems").ToListAsync();
```